# Help with a For loop and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsmutabledictionary

I am using a for loop to (currently) NSLog the contents of a NSArray. However I would like to set the contents of the array into a NSMutableDictionary, depending on the objectAtIndex it is. Currently there are 843 objects in the array, and therefore I would rather not have to type out the same thing over and over again!

My code currently is this

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (int i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i ++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [chunks objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

I would like to set the contents of the array into the NSMutableDictionary in the following fashion, and once the objectAtIndex is 11, I would like to set the 12th object in the dictionary to be of the key @"type" and soforth:

```
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"type"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"street"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"address1"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"address2"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:5] forKey:@"town"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:6] forKey:@"county"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:7] forKey:@"postcode"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:8] forKey:@"number"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:9] forKey:@"coffee club"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:10] forKey:@"latitude"];
[dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:11] forKey:@"longitude"];
```

Comment: What is your question?  It seems to me that the code you have there already does exactly what you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I think that your `chunks` array contains a long list of data, ordered in the same way (i.e. 0th, 12th, 24th, 36th... elements are all `type`, and 1st, 13th, 25th, 37th... elements are all `name`). If this is the case, you could use something like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"type", @"name", @"street", @"address1", @"address2", @"town", @"county", @"postcode", @"number", @"coffee club", @"latitude", @"longitude", nil];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i += [keys count])
{
    NSArray *subarray = [chunks subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, [keys count])];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:subarray forKeys:keys];
    
    // do something with dict

    [dict release];
}
```

Note that you can't have two different values for the same key with `NSDictionary`. That is, if you set two different values for the `type` key, only the last value set will be kept.

#### Edit

If your array is not a multiple of 12 because for example it contains garbage data at the end, you could use a different looping style instead:

```
// max should be a multiple of 12 (number of elements in keys array)
NSUInteger max = [chunks count] - ([chunks count] % [keys count]);
NSUInteger i = 0;

while (i < max)
{
    NSArray *subarray = [chunks subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, [keys count])];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:subarray forKeys:keys];
    
    // do something with dict

    [dict release];
    
    i += [keys count];
}
```

Comment: I think that it would work, but I am getting the error: *** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: index 9779 beyond bounds [0 .. 9776]' anyideas how to fix it?

Comment: @XcodeDev: I think that might be because you have an odd number of items in your array. Ideally the array size should be a multiple of 12, because there are 12 keys. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but now the keys dont match their 'chunk', and some 'chunks' are not making their way into the dictionary. i.e phone number in most cases!

Comment: @XcodeDev: Are you sure that the data is appearing in the array in the correct order, that is, index 0, 12, 24, 36 contain the correct value for `type`, and 1, 13, 25, 37 contain the correct value for `name` ?

Comment: @XcodeDev: The data is not well-formed, the first line of that file contains 13 separate fields, and the second line contains 12. I think perhaps there is a comma in the address, causing the splitting to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no pattern to your keys, you're better off doing it manually like you're doing it now.

Comment: problem is there is 843 different objects in the array.

Comment: Well I mean, there's no logical pattern. If you were doing something like A, B, C, D, etc., it would be much easier. To a computer, your labels have no logical progression, if that makes any sense. What you could do is store all of the keys in a `.plist` and recall them sort of how @Anomie suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward thing to do would be to use the code you posted. But if you really want to use a loop, something like this should do.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"type", @"name", @"street", @"address1", @"address2", @"town", @"county", @"postcode", @"number", @"coffee club", @"latitude", @"longitude", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (int i = 0; i < [chunks count] && i < [keys count]; i ++) {
    [dict setObject:[chunks objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"type",@"name",@"street",@"address1",@"address2",@"town",@"county",@"postcode",@"number",@"coffee club",@"latitude",@"longitude",nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i ++){
        [dict setObject:[chucks objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]]; 
    }
```